# How to change docker default ip binding?

Tags: docker

When Docker starts, it creates a virtual interface `docker0` and binds it to private subnet `172.17.42.1/16`. How to change this default to another ip block e.g. `192.168.42.1/24`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not always assign `172.17.42.1/16`, normally it chooses from a private range defined by RFC 1918 that are not in use on the host machine.

For changing it to a desired value you can use the following option:

```
--bip=CIDR — supply a specific IP address and netmask for the docker0 like "--bip=192.168.42.1/8"
```

More information can be seen for this on [Advanced Networking with Docker](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#docker0).